# (cordova 4.3.0) Flashlight plugin doesn't work , no errors are throwed in console

Tags: android, cordova

first thing first , sorry for my REALLY BAD ENGLIGH , and my coding skill too 
i know so many questions say about plugins do not work .... but im bagging my head over more than one week before i decided ask this question .

im using ubuntu 12.04  with cordova 4.3.0 and Flashlight plugin , trying to turn on flashlight in android .
but when i the open app, nothing happen , open Chrome Developer Tools to view error in console , but no error is showed ...
here is my code :

```
    <body>
    <h2 onclick="window.plugins.flashlight.toggle();">Flash light </h2>
    <script src='cordova.js'></script>
    <script  src="js/Flashlight.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("deviceready",Ondeviceready,false);
        function Ondeviceready(){
        window.plugins.flashlight.available(function(isAvailable) {
      if (isAvailable) {

        // switch on
        window.plugins.flashlight.switchOn(); // success/error callbacks may be passed

        // switch off after 3 seconds
        setTimeout(function() {
          window.plugins.flashlight.switchOff(); // success/error callbacks may be passed
        }, 3000);

      } else {
        alert("Flashlight not available on this device");
      }
    });
    }
    </script>
    </body>
```

Thanks for any answer !

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the plugin xml to the config.xml?
If not add it.

Ex:
xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" //add this is widget tag

Comment: Thanks ! 
i fixed it somehow @@, i dont know why @@